# Shorten SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate a boolean expression like this

```
((('a' or 'b') AND ('c' or 'd') AND ('e' or 'f')) IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM...))
```

('a', 'b'... are all strings)

Of course if I write a query like that, SQL Server will throw error because 'a', 'b'... are not boolean type.

Can anyone help me to write a shorter query to calculate that expression than below one:

`((('a' in (select..)) or (('b' in (select...))) 
AND ((('c' in (select..)) or (('d' in  (select...))) 
AND ((('e' in (select..)) or (('f' in (select...)))`

Thanks.

```
`EDIT: add more infor about my query`
```

This is my query (of course it didnot work)

```
SELECT ID, Name, Addr, PhoneNumber, Descr FROM CusInfo 
WHERE Type_ID = 'type_01' 
AND `((('a' or 'b') AND ('c' or 'd') AND ( 'e' or 'f')) IN (SELECT Cri_ID FROM CusCri WHERE CusCri.Cus_ID = CusInfo.ID))`
```

All I want is to calculate `(('a' or 'b') AND ('c' or 'd') AND ( 'e' or 'f')) IN (SELECT Cri_ID FROM CusCri WHERE CusCri.Cus_ID = CusInfo.ID)` as a boolean.

Comment: Show us some more code so we can see where it might be possible to shorten the SQL code

Comment: Updated my answer following further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (updated, following amended question):

```
SELECT ID, Name, Addr, PhoneNumber, Descr FROM CusInfo i
WHERE Type_ID = 'type_01' AND 
      3 = (select count(distinct case when c.Cri_ID in ('a','b') then 1
                                      when c.Cri_ID in ('c','d') then 2
                                      when c.Cri_ID in ('e','f') then 3
                                 end)
           from CusCri c
           WHERE c.Cus_ID = i.ID and c.Cri_ID in ('a','b','c','d','e','f') )
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
After seeing the actual table structure, this should work:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Name, 
    Addr, 
    PhoneNumber, 
    Descr,
    MeetsCriteria = ( CASE WHEN COUNT(CI.Cus_ID) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )

FROM CusInfo CI
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CusCri CC ON CusInfo.ID = CusCri.Cus_ID

WHERE [Type_ID] = 'type_01'
    AND ( CusCri.Cri_ID = 'a' OR  CusCri.Cri_ID 'b' )
    AND ( CusCri.Cri_ID = 'c' OR  CusCri.Cri_ID 'd' )
    AND ( CusCri.Cri_ID = 'e' OR  CusCri.Cri_ID 'f' )

GROUP BY
    ID, 
    Name, 
    Addr, 
    PhoneNumber, 
    Descr,
    CusCri.Cri_ID
```

**OLD ANSWER - Leaving for Reference**

A self join may be faster than a bunch of `IN` statements (test and see).

```
    SELECT MT1.* FROM MyTable MT1
    INNER JOIN MyTable MT2 ON MT1.Column1 = MT2.Column1 AND MT1.Column1 = 'A' OR MT1.Column1 = 'B'

etc...
```

I would need to see the data structures to know if this was a viable method or not.

Here is a more concrete example that I created against some of my own real data; I would only consider this a good practice if it were **not** used against textual data with wildcards (especially the non-sargable "%T"), but it's the easiest way to demonstrate it.

```
SELECT SE1.Caption FROM SearchEntity SE1
INNER JOIN SearchEntity SE2 ON SE1.Caption = SE2.Caption 
    AND 
    (
        -- starts with A or B
        ( SE1.Caption LIKE 'A%' OR SE2.Caption LIKE 'B%' ) 
         -- starts with C and ends with T
        OR ( SE1.Caption LIKE 'C%' AND SE1.Caption LIKE '%T' ) 
    )
```

Comment: Thanks you but this did not work :( (I already fixed a little errors). I will use Mark's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

```
with t1(col1) as (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM...)
select * from t1
where 'a' in (t1.Col1) or 'b' in (t1.col1) ...etc...
```